# Unauthorized Error while Trying to Debug Spring Boot Rest Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Rest Controllers.

When I try to debug application with Intellij IDEA, by right click MyApplication>Debug or Run>Debug, the application starts up and debugger says it's connected.
But none of the breakpoints inside my controllers are getting triggered, and all requests start to fail with 401 unauthorized. If I run without debugging, everything works fine.

If something rejects all incoming requests with status 401, it's the reason why breakpoints are not triggered. My code is never executed. But why the requests fail with 401 then in the debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing @SpringBootApplication annotation of the main class as following solves the issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

This excludes and disables Spring Boot's auto configurations about security. It tries to protect the API with a default user and generated password.

But I still cannot understand why this security auto configuration only gets activated while debugging and keeps disabled while running normally.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this with the limited information you gave (no code, nor a minimal reproducable example).

Spring security uses Aspect oriented programming to provide security mechanisms.It does this by executing some extra code that is not part of the code that you wrote by using a proxy. Aspect oriented programming can execute some extra code in the following ways

1. Before: Code is executed before your code gets executed
2. After: Code is executed after your method
3. AfterReturning: Code gets executed after your method has returned succesfully
4. AfterThrowing: Code gets executed after your code throws an exception
5. Around: Code gets executed before and after

In the case of security this is typically done before the method. So First the check is done to see in this case if you are authorized. In this case you are not so the method does not get executed.

Comment: Project doesn't include Spring Security (no dependency in pom.xml) AOP dependency is present and there is one aspect that I defined with @Before. But even the breakpoint in that aspect is not triggered. The issue is when the application is run with debug enabled, otherwise everthing works as expected. The behavior is changing according to whether it's running in debugger or not. I will edit my post to include some sample code

Comment: Ok, but if you are using Spring boot then there is the class SecurityAutoConfiguration which configures Spring Security by default.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a new problem when I hit on the `@RestController` but my hit couldn't reach the controller, because I installed the spring security in the maven, `Just I removed the spring security dependency

> org.springframework.boot
>             spring-boot-starter-security
>          `